# php include statement unable to open stream to file in directory above current directory

Tags: php, include, relative-path, filepath

I am trying to include a file in a different directory using a relative file path however I keep getting the error:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The path of the file calling the include statement is

```
wp-content/plugins/php-code-widget/execphp.php
```

and the file I'm trying to include is

```
wp-content/uploads/espresso/templates/sidebar_widgets/register_widget.php
```

This is my include statement:

```
<?php include ('../../uploads/espresso/templates/sidebar_widgets/register_widget.php ?>
```

Anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid the relative path.

So long as WordPress hasn't changed too much since I last used it, try something like...

```
include ABSPATH . 
     'wp-content/uploads/espresso/templates/sidebar_widgets/register_widget.php';
```